# How to replace the first and last letter in EditPad?

Tags: regex, editpad

In EditPad I want to replace `<foo far baz>` to `<p>foo far baz</p>`

To serach/locate the string I use: `<.*?\w>`

My question is, how to write the replace command? On https://www.regular-expressions.info/refreplacebackref.html I could not find command to replace the first and last letter.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this regex,

```
(\<)([^<>]*)(\>)
```

and replace with

```
\1p>\2</p\3
```